# Использование RDP как прокси для подключения к БД

Tags: rdp, dbeaver

Для подключения к рабочей сети используется VPN.
Без включённого VPN по RDP не подключишься к серверу на Win 2008.
После подключения VPN, заходим на удалённый сервер Win 2008, на нём запускаем DBeaver и уже с него подключаемся к нужной нам БД (БД конечно же лежит на другом сервере), будь то Postgres или MS.
Сам вопрос: Если включить VPN на локальном ПК, то можно ли в настройка ПО для доступа к БД (например DBeaver) прописать настройку прокси или т.п. для того, чтобы не заходя по RDP подключаться к БД?